# How to control text height of textview in android?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, view, textview

I have text-view which occupies the whole screen in the landscape mode. If I increase the text-size(font-size) attribute ... part of the text gets hidden. I would appreciate if somebody can let me know how to control just the height of the text so that I can elongate the text without affecting the width.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to change the 'aspect ratio' of the text? I dont think you can do that. You'd be better off finding a font or creating your own font which meets your requirements.

Package the font with the app as an asset and use it (http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/)

Comment: +1. If you *can*, you *shouldn't*. Few things are uglier in a UI than disproportionate text. Find a Condensed font to use instead -- Google's own Roboto has Condensed, Condensed Italic, Bold Condensed, and Bold Condensed Italic weights, and is free to use. You can download it here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Comment: This font resolved my issue.  http://www.dafont.com/tall-films.font?psize=l&text=00%3A 
Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.